# URL validation in TCL

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to download a file over HTTP using http package in TCL. If the given URL is correct then everything is going fine but if the given URL is wrong then it is not throwing any errors. Now my question is that How to validate given URL using TCL?

Thanks in Advance,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

The http package doesn't throw errors for most failures (except host resolution); you have to check for them with the [`http::ncode`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/http.htm#M40) command.

```
set token [http::geturl $theWrongUrl]
if {[http::ncode $token] >= 400} {
    error "http problem: [string range [http::code $token] 13 end]"
}
```

(This code will leak a token; it omits the `http::cleanup` call…)